# How to discard null coordinate points automatically when we make Multipoint Geometry in Spatialite?

Tags: spatialite

I have a Spatialite table that contains a series of 80 coordinates where each coordinate placed into one column in a table. Then, I want to add all those coordinates into one Multipoint Geometry Column. Unfortunately, some of those coordinates have NULL value randomly. This will make the Multipoint Geometry Column having NULL value as well.

I tried to catch the NULL value using CASE WHEN, but since the table has 80 columns, my CASE WHEN code becomes very long because I must check it column by column.

Is there any automatic way to discard/unconsidered NULL coordinate points when we make a Multipoint Geomatry Column?

Comment: I'd try to fix the data first. What does "NULL" represent in those columns?

Comment: Null represent no coordinates in that column, may be it similar to N/A.

Comment: OK.... Perhaps you can say what the columns represent?